# How to present and dismiss modal view from appdelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am in the appdelegate of my application, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and I'd like to load a modal navigation controller over a tab bar controller (I dont' have a class "navigation controller" but only a navigation controller in the storyboard with a view controller that "segue" the navigation controller). Then I'd like to return to the tab bar controller. 
In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I've used this code and the modal navigation controller works fine:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login Controller"];
self.window.rootViewController = loginController;
```

But when in my modal view controller the "segue" the navigation controller I try to return to tab bar with this code:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

Nothing appens. What's is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: [self.navigatorcontroller presentviewController: Controller];

Comment: Your question is more of how do I dismiss a `UINavigationController` its not really about presenting. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is also that I load a navigation controller with "root view controller" and not with a modal transition. I'd like to load a modal navigation controller over the tab bar controller, in this way later I can use dismissViewController

Comment: I know this is old but, @user2136333 have you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is how we setting which view controller need to be the rootViewController (The firstViewController need to show).

```
mainViewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I dismiss thies rootViewController and return to tabBarController?

Comment: Its impossible. But you can set tabBarcontroller as rootView controller and present the other view controller from tabBarController. Or you can present tabBarController from the rootViewController.

Comment: or you can change view of rootViewController to view of tabBarController by assigning, 'mainViewController.view = tabBarController.view'

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
[self.navigatorcontroller presentviewController: Controller];
```

To present view Controller

And you can dismiss it by

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: in AppDelegate i have a error if I use self.navigatorcontroller